# Show that the series of derivatives of an entire function converges

Tags: complex-analysis

I was asked to show that if $f(z)$ is holomorphic at a neighbourhood of $a$, and $\sum_{n\geq0}f^{(n)}(a)$ converges, then $f$ is entire and $\sum_{n\geq0}f^{(n)}(z)$ converges for all z in the complex plane.It is easy to prove that $f$ is entire since $f^{(n)}(a)$ is bounded and $\frac{|z-a|^{n}}{n!}$ is smaller than a geometric sequence for sufficiently large $n$.
I have trouble with the second assertion. I can only get the result when the convergence at $a$ is absolute. The method was shown [Show that the series of derivatives of a certain entire function converges everywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592261/show-that-the-series-of-derivatives-of-a-certain-entire-function-converges-every). But for the non-absolute convergent case, I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a=0$
$$\sum_{m=0}^M f^{(m)}(z) = \sum_{m=0}^M\sum_{k\ge 0} f^{(k+m)}(0) \frac{z^k}{k!}
 = \sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{z^k}{k!} \sum_{m=0}^M f^{(k+m)}(0)= \sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{z^k}{k!}(b_k-b_{k+M+1}) $$

where $b_k = \sum_{m=0}^\infty f^{(k+m)}(0)$ converges and $\lim_{k\to \infty} b_k=0$.

Whence $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty f^{(m)}(z)=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{z^k}{k!}b_k- \lim_{M\to \infty} \sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{z^k}{k!} b_{k+M+1}$$

$$=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{z^k}{k!}b_k- \lim_{M\to \infty} O( \exp(|z|) \sup_{k>M}|b_k|) =\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{z^k}{k!}b_k$$